# Using Map for object value pair with array value nested in another Map function in javascript

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I have existing JSON data, and I would like to build a similar JSON object using map functions, however the nested `.map()` methods are returning the data type and not the actual data for the output.

I have this starting data:

```
{
        "id": 111,
        "other_id": 111,
        "name": "name",
        "display_name": "display name",
        "type": "type",
        "required": true,
        "sort_order": 0,
        "config": {
            "config_one": true,
            "config_two": true,
            "config_three": "weight"
        },
        "option_values": [
            {
                "id": 2222,
                "other_option_id": 2222,
                "label": "Option Value Label",
                "sort_order": 0,
                "value_data": {
                    "separate_object_id": 3333
                },
                "is_default": false,
                "adjusters": {
                    "price": null,
                    "weight": null,
                    "image_url": "",
                    "enable_disable_flag": {
                        "status": false,
                        "message": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And would like it to result in this data after map function:

```
{
    "display_name": "display name",
    "type": "type",
    "required": true,
    "sort_order": 0,
    "config": {
            "config_one": true,
            "config_two": true,
            "config_three": "weight"
    },
    "option_values": [
        {
            "label": "Option Value Label",
            "sort_order": 0,
            "value_data": {
                "separate_object_id": 3333
            },
            "is_default": false,
            "adjusters": {
                "price": null,
                "weight": null,
                "image_url": "",
                "enable_disable_flag": {
                    "status": false,
                    "message": ""
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my current map method function that I'm using, that is not working:

```
  modifier.map(item => {
      let returnedItem = {
        display_name: item.display_name,
        type: item.type,
        required: item.required,
        sort_order: item.sort_order,
        config: item.config,
        option_values: item.option_values.map(opt_valItems => ({ 
          label: opt_valItems.label, 
          sort_order: opt_valItems.sort_order,
          value_data: opt_valItems.value_data,
          is_default: opt_valItems.is_default,
          adjusters: item.adjusters
        }))
      }  
    })
```

Comment: your map doenst return anything

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: What is `modifier` in your code? It's clearly not the structure quoted at the beginning of the question, since that object doesn't have a `map` method. Is it an array of that structure? What are you doing with map`'s return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` always returns a new Array. So you need to assign this into a new variable. Also, there was a slight problem in your code. You were using `let returnedItem` inside the `map`, but were not returning anything. Fixed that.

```js
var modifier = [{
        "id": 111,
        "other_id": 111,
        "name": "name",
        "display_name": "display name",
        "type": "type",
        "required": true,
        "sort_order": 0,
        "config": {
            "config_one": true,
            "config_two": true,
            "config_three": "weight"
        },
        "option_values": [
            {
                "id": 2222,
                "other_option_id": 2222,
                "label": "Option Value Label",
                "sort_order": 0,
                "value_data": {
                    "separate_object_id": 3333
                },
                "is_default": false,
                "adjusters": {
                    "price": null,
                    "weight": null,
                    "image_url": "",
                    "enable_disable_flag": {
                        "status": false,
                        "message": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }]


 var x = modifier.map(item => {
      return {
        display_name: item.display_name,
        type: item.type,
        required: item.required,
        sort_order: item.sort_order,
        config: item.config,
        option_values: item.option_values.map(opt_valItems => ({ 
          label: opt_valItems.label, 
          sort_order: opt_valItems.sort_order,
          value_data: opt_valItems.value_data,
          is_default: opt_valItems.is_default,
          adjusters: item.adjusters
        }))
      }  
    });
    
    console.log(x)
```

Comment: *"Also, fixed your code slightly"* Please call out the changes you made, and why you made them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks @T.J.Crowder  But the option_values still is just returning [Object] :(

Comment: Nvm, this was console printing issue with console.log that made me believe the values weren't there. Thanks again. For others that MIGHT have this issue, I stringified the json, then printed it as such `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` This made it print all the nested items.